# Canvas stream screen live

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to get screen continous (so live), and not only on load page.

This is my example where it work and get screen of webpage, but only when page is loaded,
If I set setInterval, than browser ask me everytime permission.

```
// my script.js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
// Request media
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia().then(stream => {

    // Grab frame from stream
    let track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    let capture = new ImageCapture(track);
    capture.grabFrame().then(bitmap => {
        //track.stop();

        // Draw the bitmap to canvas
        canvas.width = bitmap.width;
        canvas.height = bitmap.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            // Do things with blob here
            console.log('output blob:', blob);
            const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            document.getElementById('preview').src = img;
        })
    });
})
```

Here HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:none"></canvas>
<img id="preview" style="width: 350px;height: 350px" src="">
```

https://codepen.io/MoKu23/pen/MWVMLgP

Comment: The codepen does not show the problem - could you show us code which does (I imagine that means add in whatever the setInterval does).

Comment: Added code separated in script HTML and JS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the MDN article on user display media is with an example that fails on many systems and in many apps. On Opera 77 ( [here](https://www.browserling.com/browse/win7/opera77/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture%23result) ), it is like an [infinity mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_mirror), so the solution may be in browser setting that a website would not want to alter.

So there is an  html2canvas API that would take the page screen kind of to the canvas and get some result, at least.

There are still solutions. The browser is requesting a permit each time. But there should be a setting not to ask each time ( and you need to inform your user of that if that is the case ).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `<canvas>` nor an `<img>` but a `<video>`:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia().then((stream) => {
  document.querySelector("video").srcObject = stream;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lptc8no0/

And if you want to grab the still image from each frame draw that `<video>` on the canvas.